# image URL wont load in ie but will load in Firefox browser

Tags: html, wordpress, browser

I have a weird problem,
this URL won't load in internet explorer 7 or 8 but will load in Firefox 3 and 7.
can anyone tell me what it can possibly be?

```
http://raandassociates.com/wp-content/themes/theme/images/banner1.jpg
```

this is the main page that the image needs to be loaded on and for some reason since that path doesn't work the images won't show on the homepage.

http://raandassociates.com/

I have tried http://www. and http:// and without the http://

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested with http://browserling.com and it works for me.

Comment: i found out the issue for anyone else having the issue. ie doesnt reconize cmyk images. the images were saved as cymk and i just changed it to rgb and it works. you must've looked after i changed it.